# xpath to get data out of nested element

Tags: php, xpath

I am working on an interface with the amazon product advertising API.

I have XML that includes a section similar to this:

```
<BrowseNodes>
  <BrowseNode>
     <Name>Category</Name>
     <BrowseNodeId>123456</BrowseNodeId>
     <Ancestors>
       <BrowseNode>
         <Name>Whatever</Name>
        <BrowseNodeId>987654</BrowseNodeId>
       <BrosweNode>
     </Ancestors>
  </BroseNode>
  <BroseNode>
  ...
  </BrowseNode>
</BrowseNodes>
```

I'll have to double check my XML. there might be one more level of `<BrowseNode>` `</BrowseNode>` outside of the first `<BrowseNode>` I posted above.

I need to find the `<BrowseNode>` `<Name>` that is inside the Ancestors element where the `<Ancestors>` element is a sibling of the `<Name>`Category`</Name>`

I'm just getting started with xpath, and that's over my head.

I have been coding it like this:

```
//$XML fromapi
$parsed=simplexml_load_string($XML);

//narrow it down
$s = '/ItemSearchResponse/Items/Item';
$items = $parsed->xpath($s);

//Get only the top level BrowseNodes for this item.
foreach($items as $item)
  {
    // this narrows it down close to what I posted above.
    $s = 'BrowseNodes/BrowseNode';
    $top_browsenode_search=$item->xpath($s);

      //there may be a simpler way, but I think it is working for me:
      foreach ($top_browsenode_search as $top_browsenode)
        {
          $temp_array=array();//must be emptied each time.
          $s = 'Name';
          $temp_array['name']=$top_browsenode->xpath($s);
          $s = 'BrowseNodeId';
          $temp_array['id']=$top_browsenode->xpath($s);

      $browsenodes[]=$temp_array;
        }
    $top_browsenodes[]=$browsenodes;
    unset ($browsenodes);        
  }
```

Is anyone able to help with that xpath syntax? If not directly, could you point me to any novice friendly documentation you know of? I downloaded a great book on the subject, I've learned a lot from it, but It's a little over my head.

below is not part of the question, but rather evidence that one of the answers was correct. See the comments for details.
Expected result: "Whatever" Given Result: "Whatever"

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
<BrowseNodes>
  <BrowseNode>
     <Name>Category</Name>
     <BrowseNodeId>123456</BrowseNodeId>
     <Ancestors>
       <BrowseNode>
         <Name>Whatever</Name>
         <BrowseNodeId>987654</BrowseNodeId>
       </BrowseNode>
     </Ancestors>
  </BrowseNode>
  <BrowseNode>
     <Name>SomethingElse</Name>
     <BrowseNodeId>951753</BrowseNodeId>
  </BrowseNode>
</BrowseNodes>
</root>
BrowseNodes/BrowseNode/Name
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Category
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => SomethingElse
        )

)

BrowseNodes/BrowseNode[Name="Category"]/Ancestors/BrowseNode/Name 
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Whatever
        )

)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get just the node:

```
BrowserNodes/BrowserNode[Name=_______]/Ancestors/BrowserNode/Name
```

If you want to get the node's text:

```
BrowserNodes/BrowserNode[Name=_______]/Ancestors/BrowserNode/Name/text()
```

In both examples, replace ***_*** with the name for which you are searching.

Comment: Thanks, It looks like I need your second one and I'd do $s = 'BrowseNodes/BrowseNode[Name=Category]/Ancestors/BrowserNode/Name/text()'  But does this traverse the depth, or do I need to know how deeply it's nested?

Comment: If you are unsure how deeply `BrowserNodes` (with an "s") is nested, add `descendant::` in front of the whole thing.  By the way, I know very little about this level of XPath.  I'm just using [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp).

Comment: I find (at least for me) there's always a learning curve, even in understanding the documentation of a new technology. I'm still working on this one, so I appreciate the fact that you are able to break that info down to my current level. I'll take this and use to not only get this piece of data, but to further my understanding of xpath queries. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help!  It certainly is does have an interesting learning curve, but I've been working with it long enough (on a different level) to be able to understand the documentation, fortunately.

Comment: I didn't accept this answer, but once my reputation is high enough, I'll up-vote it anyway. See my comment below for the code that worked. I'd bet that if my XML was exactly like what I posted here, Z's answer would have been correct.

Comment: Interesting... a double-slash.  I can't say I remember what that does, though I think I recall using it before.  We should figure out if my code works for the XML that you posted so that we don't mislead the next person who finds this page.

Comment: I'm going to post a reply as a modification to my question because it won't fit here.

Answer (score -1):

Find below example:

```
<?php
$xmlString ="
<BrowseNodes>
  <BrowseNode>
     <Name>Category</Name>
     <BrowseNodeId>123456</BrowseNodeId>
     <Ancestors>
       <BrowseNode>
         <Name>Whatever</Name>
        <BrowseNodeId>987654</BrowseNodeId>   
        </BrowseNode>
     </Ancestors>
  </BrowseNode>
 <BrowseNode>
     <Name>Category</Name>
     <BrowseNodeId>123456</BrowseNodeId>
     <Ancestors>
       <BrowseNode>
         <Name>Whatever</Name>
        <BrowseNodeId>987654</BrowseNodeId>   
        </BrowseNode>
     </Ancestors>
  </BrowseNode>   
</BrowseNodes>";
$result=  simplexml_load_string($xmlString); 
$counter =0;
$newArray=array();
foreach($result->BrowseNode as $arr) {
    $newArray[$counter]['Name'] =(string)$arr->Name;
    $newArray[$counter]['BrowseNodeId'] =(string)$arr->BrowseNodeId;
    $newArray[$counter]['Ancestors']['Name'] =(string)$arr->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Name;
    $newArray[$counter]['Ancestors']['BrowseNodeId'] =(string)$arr->Ancestors->BrowseNode->BrowseNodeId;    
    $counter++;
}
print"<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
die;
?>
```

Comment: This isn't really what the original poster was asking.  TecBrat is already able to use this technique, I believe.  Now (s)he wants to simplify it using XPath.

Comment: I acually re-worded my question and posted it again. I was given this code and it worked:  `BrowseNodes/BrowseNode//BrowseNode[Name="Categories"]` Looks like what I really needed was that double slash. I've been able now to do several similar searches using just that little bit of new knowledge. **he**             :)

Comment: Oh, I left off part of my working code: `BrowseNodes/BrowseNode//BrowseNode[Name="Categories"]/Ancestors/BrowseNode/Name/text()`